# How to fix Email Authentication issue in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am sending email when user register but when I run my page it is showing me an error like this

> Swift_TransportException: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with
>   username "support@project.gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators.
>   Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code
>   "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

Comment: Can you show me your `mail.php`?

Answer (score 0):

if you are in development / local environment you can use service like [mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io) and put credentials in `.env` file